# What Is the Learning Rate Parameter in Adadelta Optimiser for in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

In Keras, there is an Adadelta optimiser for SGD as follows:

```py
optimizer = optimizers.Adadelta(lr=1.0, rho=0.95, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
```

Here is the doc.: https://keras.io/optimizers/#adadelta
But as we know, Adadelta does not use any learning rate. So what is lr for?

Comment: No, your statement that adadelta does not use a learning rate is incorrect

Comment: @Matias Valenegro. Here is the original paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5701.pdf. See Section 3.1, please. However, Kears does add a learning rate, see code  line #411, https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L353. Seems it changes the original algorithm a bit. But I do not know why.

Comment: @Matias. OP was using the royal "we" :)

Comment: Look at equation 10, η is the learning rate you are looking for

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I am afraid I hardly agree. Equation 10 is for the original Adagrad algorithm, and replacing η with the previous RMS[∆x^2]t−1 is exactly where Adadelta innovates so as to solve the so-called vanishing gradient problem.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, got you, chap*_^

Comment: Keras does not implement that algorithm, its actually not the algorithm that everybody knows as adadelta, even the documentation tells you that it has a learning rate and that the key innovation is a scaling by a moving window of gradients.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I see. Thanks for the clarification, but as a matter a fact, if you take a look at line  #410 `update = g * K.sqrt(d_a + self.epsilon) / K.sqrt(new_a + self.epsilon)`, Keras does adopt the idea from Adadelta, not Adagrad. Such a fact is further proved by line #420, where `new_d_a = self.rho * d_a + (1 - self.rho) * K.square(update)`

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro If I understood the Adadelta paper correctly, it does not use explicit learning rate. The η in equation (10) is just a placeholder for the idea explained in the next section of the paper. The Keras implementation is indeed Adadelta, with just a slight modification to preserve the elegant modularity of the framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why such design decision was made?

It is indeed a very interesting question. Let's see how this is described in Keras documentation:

> In the original version of Adadelta you don't have to set an initial learning rate. In this version, initial learning rate and decay factor can be set, as in most other Keras optimizers.

So the documentations itself admits that this method doesn't need a learning rate. I believe this design decision was made because of some other templates, dependencies, or codes in the project.

More specifically, the philosophy of keras is **you can combine any building blocks you want** (i.e. a unified API). If you remove the parameter `lr` from this, I believe you won't be able to use some of the **callbacks**.

---

### Comparison

Now, let's compare the [Adadelta implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L350) of Keras to the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5701.pdf):

- [Line 406:](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L406) here the gradients are accumulated into a moving average (`a` is the moving average, `rho` is decay rate as in the paper, `g` is computed gradients for parameter `p`):

  ```python
  new_a = self.rho * a + (1. - self.rho) * K.square(g)
  self.updates.append(K.update(a, new_a))
  ```

  This perfectly corresponds to the following line in the algorithm:

  [image]
- [Line 410:](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L410) delta calculation (here, `d_a` is delta accumulator, also in the form of moving average):

  ```python
  update = g * K.sqrt(d_a + self.epsilon) / K.sqrt(new_a + self.epsilon)
  ```

  This perfectly corresponds to

  [image]
- [Line 411:](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L411) now **here is the tricky part.** The code looks as follows:

  ```python
  new_p = p - lr * update
  ```

  Which doesn't follows the original algorithm in the paper:

  [image]

  Furthermore, such learning rate admits changes through the learning rate decay parameter. However, the default value of `lr` in Keras is `1.0`, and `decay` is `0.0` so by default it shouldn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Yes, that is a reasonable explanation: a unified API. Thanks for the details. I would suggest that Keras doc make that clear so as to avoid any future confusions.